# How to make objects communicate with eachother?

Tags: c++, oop

For the past few weeks, I have been thinking of a way to make rather unrelated objects to communicate with each other. While I have been able to find several ways to make it work, they all seem to be somewhat unelegant or overly complicated.

One of the working solutions was to create some sort of a super-class which serves the role of a "mediator", checking the state of its member objects and responding accordingly.

```
struct SuperClass {
    Car playerCar;
    Police police;

    void update() { if(playerCar.exceedsSpeed()) { police.call(); } }
};
```

While this could work well in simple programs, this design tends to get messy with complexity. As more different object types are created, more super-classes or mid-super-classes are required. Eventually you end up with a strict hierarchy of classes which are extremely difficult to maintain.

Another solution is to pass the reference of an object as an argument.

```
struct Car {
    Police* pPolice;
    Car(Police* obj) { pPolice = obj; }
};

Police police;
Car playerCar(&police);
```

Every call to the `Police::call()` could be made through `pPolice`, but there are two issues with this solution.

First, the `Car` struct now doesn't make any sense. If every car has various characteristics such as `color`, `manufacturer`, `maxSpeed`, and so on, why the hell does every car have a `police`? Since objects are structures containing variables specific to the type of that object, including a completely unrelated variable among those variables breaks the aesthetics of OOP.

Second, in case `Car` needs to call methods of more objects than just `police.call()`, I would now need to pass more references as arguments.

`Car playerCar(&police, &anotherObj, &yetAnotherObj...)`

... And this is just silly.

Instead, I would like to be able to call the appropriate methods locally.

```
void Car::accelerate() {
    speed++;
    if (speed > maxSpeed) { Mediator::callPolice(); }
};
```

How do I do that? Is that possible? Is that even the correct way?

Comment: Maybe use an observer pattern and then the police object would be an observer of the car objects?  (Sort of even reflects how it works in real life.)

Comment: It is hard to figure out what real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You're right, unless there is a police officer in every car, `Car` containing a `Police` object makes no sense. Further, you don't want `Car` to know anything about how the police are called. Think of this as you would a logging utility. A function that does all the work, however it's done, like `callpolice()` makes sense, if a car calling the police on it'self makes any sense in the first place. buried inside the function, you can have one `Police`, a pool of `Police`, allocate new `Police` on the fly, pretty much anything you want. But `Car` shouldn't be involved in any of it.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, you are right. I think this is what Jerry meant by his answer below. I was looking for a programatical solution to a problem that is more of a logical nature.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you normally have two cases.

One is that the police catch somebody speeding. They don't call the police to report themselves--rather, an individual police officer has some area in which he can observe, and if a car exceeds the limit while traveling through that area (and the police officer isn't otherwise occupied), he's caught and gets issued a ticket (or whatever).

The second, is that the driver of the car decides to call the police (e.g., there's been an accident). In this case, there is a "mediator"-like class. Specifically, there's a class to represent the phone system, and the driver (or another driver who sees) uses their phone to call the police. If nobody with a phone sees the incident, then the police might just not get called--or there might at least be a delay while the driver finds somebody with a phone.

Comment: What you are trying to say is that the method `Police::call()` implies that this method is actually related to the `Police` objects, and therefore these objects call the police on themselves. Not only that, but the `playerCar` actually calls the police on themselves after the player exceeds the speed limit. Am I right? This quite makes sense and explains why every solutions seemed strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public static method "callPolice" inside your "Police" struct. Then you could call it from a method inside Car struct. This would work for you if body of "callPolice" method does not need to execute on an instance of a specific Police object.

Comment: The example above does not necessarily require `call()` to be executed on an instance of a specific `Police` object. So your solution would work. I, however, need two OBJECTS to communicate with eachother, and therefore I need to call a method on a specific instance of an object.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've missed the essence of your question with this answer. I've personally used QT framework for c++ which has signal/slot mechanism for achieving your desired functionality. I am not sure how to do this in pure c++ though.